# Knockout and bootstrap not binding

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I cannot get the value of my bound data-bind.  When I try to read the value it is always undefined.

I have setup a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tonymaloney1971/2qjhb5pw/5/

I think possibly the problem could be in the way I have setup the knockout binding:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = [{ PostCodeStart: "", PostCodeEnd: "", Mileage: "", Notes: ""     }];


        add: function () {
//this part is not working this.PostCodeStart() === "" 
            alert("How do I get the value of PostCodeStart");
            if (this.PostCodeStart() === "" || this.PostCodeEnd() === "" || this.Mileage() === "") {
                alert("empty field");
            }
            else
                this.journeyList.push({ PostCodeStart: this.PostCodeStart(), PostCodeEnd: this.PostCodeEnd(), Mileage: this.Mileage(), Notes: this.Notes() });
        },
```

Also, in my fiddle you will notice that a

dot is added each time I add a new row, how can I not display the

.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using knockout to bind the click events for your add/delete buttons?

Comment: Hi Roy,  I did try but I could not get knockbind binding working for the add/ remove buttons.  But I am a work in progress so just starting out with knockout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a modified Fiddle that gets the data to your add and remove functions. As a general rule, you will not be using `this` to make knockout work. As a side-note, Douglas Crockford makes a fair case for never using `this` in his talk about [class-free OOP](https://youtu.be/bo36MrBfTk4?t=19m48s).

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
                    <button class="btn-success img-rounded" data-bind="click:$root.add">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="text-align:right"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn-danger img-rounded" data-bind="click:$root.remove">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </button>
```

And the viewModel:

```
    var viewModel = {
        journeyList: ko.observableArray(data),
        add: function (data) {
            if (data.PostCodeStart === "" || data.PostCodeEnd === "" || data.Mileage === "") {
                alert("empty field");
            }
            else {
                viewModel.journeyList.push({ PostCodeStart: data.PostCodeStart, PostCodeEnd: data.PostCodeEnd, Mileage: data.Mileage, Notes: data.Notes });
            }
        },

        remove: function (data) {
            viewModel.journeyList.remove(data);
        }
    };
```

Updated: added style to the list to eliminate the bullets.

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: journeyList" style="list-style-type:none">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q6cjygy1/1/

Comment: I don't go along with the tip of never using "this" in JavaScript. It's an integral part of the language, avoiding it "just because" is not a useful recommendation. That being said, you will however generally want to completely avoid binding your events with jQuery (outside of custom binding definitions) when you use knockout.

Comment: I said you generally won't use "this" to make Knockout work; OP was expecting to get data members from "this" rather than the passed-in data argument.
Crockford's argument for never using "this" is not "just because". I provided a link because it's an interesting argument.

Comment: Well Roy, thank you so much.  You have not only solved the problem but I have learned from your knowledge.  Thanks for taking the time and I will check the video out.  Thank you very much